# How do I create a manual object with colors for each vertex?

Tags: shaders, 3d-meshes, ogre, vertex, materials

How do I create a shaded manual object with colours for each vertex?
Eg if `ogreObj` is the `Ogre::ManualObject` :

```
ogreObj->begin("BaseWhiteNoLighting", Ogre::RenderOperation::OT_TRIANGLE_LIST);
```

will allow me to select each vertex's colour with `ogreObj->colour(r, g, b)`
after each `ogreObj->position(x, y, z)` and `ogreObj->normal(x, y, z)` call.

However, if I change the material to `BaseWhite`, `color()` instructions are ignored.
I read that you must disable lighting int the `.material` script, but I need it active...
Any advice?

**ANSWER:** [This Ogre forum's thread](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=35383&start=0) has a simple `.material` script that works for this purpose:

```
material Voxel/Default
{
   technique
   {
      pass
      {
         diffuse vertexcolour
         specular vertexcolour
         ambient vertexcolour
         lighting on

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: have you tried using a custom material, similar to the base one, but with your own vertex and pixel shaders?

Comment: Like this http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=35383&start=0

Comment: Thank you both! But the thread teodron linked at worked for me. Specifically, I just made a `.material` script with this content: `material Voxel/Default
{
   technique
   {
      pass
      {
         diffuse vertexcolour
         specular vertexcolour
         ambient vertexcolour
         lighting on
         
      }
   }
}`

Comment: I can't answer my question... :|

Comment: Put your update in the question, as an edit. I can't answer it either because I just did that in a comment by supplying a link. There's an "ethical" rule: if you supply a link and not an explanation,  you should comment and not answer. When you get the reputation, you'll answer it yourself :).

Comment: You can answer your own question, you just have to wait a while. Please *don't* "answer" the question by placing the answer text in the question itself. I've reposted your answer as an actual answer; feel free to post your version if you like and I will delete mine.

Answer (score 1):

As you discovered, a material script can be used for this purpose.

```
material Voxel/Default
{
   technique
   {
      pass
      {
         diffuse vertexcolour
         specular vertexcolour
         ambient vertexcolour
         lighting on

      }
   }
}
```